# Is this simple XPath query correct?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a document that has the following format:

```
<Root>
    <A />
    <C />
    <B />
    <A>
        <B>
            <A />
            <C /> 
        </B>
    </A>
</Root>
```

I want to "catch" all the elements `A` and `B` and list them in a new doc:

```
<A /> <B /> <A /> <B /> ...
```

With XPath, would the query be (with `Root` as the context node):

```
.//*[A | B]
```

Comment: No. The query appears in the middle of a huge Java program, and it is not easy to debug.

Comment: Don't debug the giant program. Write a weeny teeny program that loads the data into the DOM and shoots xpaths at it, and measure the elementary particles that fly out.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short XPath expression that doesn't use any function and traverses the XML document just once. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//*[self::A or self::B]
```

This selects all elements in the document that are either `A` or `B`.

**Traverses the document only once** :)

Comment: this one is better than answer 1 and 2

Comment: Why is this answer better than `.//*[name()="A" or name()="B"]`? Doesn't that answer also traverses the document only once? Is the use of the `name()` function that bad? I sincerely don't know. I'm a XPath noob. :)

Comment: The most problematic part is the `.` at the start -- this makes the answer generally wrong. The use of the `name()` function is unnecessary in this case -- using the `self::` axis is more readable and efficient.

Comment: Why is using the dot (`.`) bad? Does it introduce unnecessary overhead?

Comment: Wow, not using the dot, saved me ~30seconds in a 3 minutes query. Really good. Please explain, why is it faster. Anyway, correct answer awarded.

Comment: `./SomeExpression` means that `SomeExpression` must be applied atarting off the current node. So, the Xpath engine spends some effort  in establishing which is the current node. I am surprized that there is such big difference in efficiency. I recommended not to use `.`, because your XPath expression will select different sets of nodes depending on which is the current node when the expression evaluation is started.

Comment: Correct. This would be the XPath 1.0 version of the XPath 2.0 [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903118/is-this-simple-xpath-query-correct/4903163#4903163) of Welbog

Comment: @Alejandro: Someone reading your comment would think that my solution works only in XPath 1.0. This is wrong. The XPath expression I provided is evaluated exactly in the same way and produces exactly the same result *both* under XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0. I think that such a statement can be made only in the case when an XPath 1.0 expression will be evaluated differently and will produce different results in XPath 2.0 -- and in this particular case this is not true.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are right, that setence of mine could be misundertood. My intent was to point out that @Welbog answer was a valid XPath 2.0 expression, because of the OP comments and because there was not hint in question about XPath engine version.

Answer (score 2):

Based on ***Welbog***'s answer, I came up with this one:

```
.//*[name()="A" or name()="B"]
```

It does what is supposed.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write `//A|//B`  (The previous one didn't seem to work except in one online xpath tester, that'll teach me to trust them). Although this would traverse the tree twice.

Your original expression said: give me all the elements (`//*`) that have a child called A or B (`[A|B]`), because when the predicate part (the [] bit) is evaluated, the context node is alraedy the node you're examining, so anything within the predicate is relative to that context.

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware of that fact. That's why you should always test.. Thanks. +1